# Vader Assignments not showing

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've only ever, in months of play, had ONE assignment from Vader. I got tired of waiting, so I paid the Bux to skip... It took my 10 Bux, but the assignment stayed. Question: how do I get more assignments from Vader then?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason or other, there are no more Imperial assignments for the time being since the last update. So don't spend any more bux on skipping that. Hopefully, the Imperial assignments come back once the current Imperial Propaganda Event ends.

[image: Imperial Assignment]

And the supply officer with the yellow hardhat, he doesn't shave 3 hours off your construction of floors anymore. He should immediately complete any Imperial product that you are manufacturing on your Imperial floors. For example, Product X may need 1 hour 50 mins to complete building, but once you send him there, the Product X would be ready for collection, and you can build another round of Imperial product on that floor.

Comment: The Supply Officers never took time off construction; that's the Worker, who no longer shows up randomly but can be acquired as a reward.

The Supply Officers used to be required to start building Imperial Items, but when the system was overhauled to the three-mission setup, they changed to their current function.